# Is there a way to search for unresolved feature requests?

Tags: feature-request, meta, search

A tag search will find declined, completed and "by design" feature requests but what about feature requests that haven't been declined or accepted yet. This would be a useful view to have.

Answer (score 8):

This is possible - just search questions tagged `feature-request` but not `status-completed`, `status-declined`, or `status-bydesign`:

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+-status-completed+-status-declined+-status-bydesign
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Ok, so you can do that. But that's rather awkward.

Comment: Remember to also exclude `status-sadpanda`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, do the math. There are NINE HUNDRED AND FLIPPIN' TWENTY feature-requests at the time I write this. How many of them do you think are

1. Reasonable ideas?
2. Reasonable ideas worth implementing?
3. No, *really*, it's worth spending development time to implement this?

I occasionally [browse the feature-request list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=feature-request%20-status-declined%20-status-completed%20-status-deferred&sort=votes) sorted by votes (and by that I mean most votes at the top) and that's about the best we can hope for.

This aspect of the site is very uservoice-y by definition. There are just way more ideas than we could ever implement even if we had twice the team we do now.

(and bear in mind the company has other things we're working on, that are internal priorities, as well)

Comment: Isn't this going off the handle just a bit for a question to find out if we can find unresolved feature requests?

Comment: I'm just pointing out that no search is really necessary to answer this question; all [feature-request]s are pretty much all unresolved and are likely to stay that way for a very long time -- except for those with 10+ votes.

Comment: statistically speaking, that is

Comment: By other priorities, do you happen to mean an API? I ask, because I have noticed the start of an API.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this search, which seems like it should be correct:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+-status-completed+-status-norepro+-status-declined+-status-bydesign+-status-deferred

There are currently 779 requests in that list, of which 59 are voted 10 or higher.