# How to relate a comment to a specific comment?

Tags: support, comments

How to relate a comment to a specific comment in case of multiple comments by a single SO user or when you are commenting on a specific comment which is not recent but which is down below (older) then 5-6 comments?

There should be provision to enter a comment below (time wise) the specific comment.

Comment: Just use words to make it clear what you're referring to. There's no other way

Comment: Well, turns out there is. Forgot about that one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can post direct link to a specific comment. The link is available by clicking the comment time stamp (e.g. "X minutes ago") so right click it choose "copy link address" and you can paste it.

So sample comment can look like:

> @Pekka in response to [this comment of yours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136476/how-to-relate-a-comment-to-a-specific-comment#comment381425_136476) - there is this other way. :)

Comment: Heh! True. ---------

Answer (score 8):

In this scenario, strongly consider moving the conversation into chat. If you're having trouble making it clear in your reply which comment is being responded to, chances are future readers will have an *even harder* time doing so.

Comments *really* suck for extended, threaded, discussion.

Comment: Is it okay if I simultaneously edit the answer given by me which is being commented upon and I inform the commentator?

Comment: Extended comments should be avoided but if it is very necessary and really connected to the answer or question details to have some comments then?

Comment: @Optimight: yes. You can also leave a fairly lengthy explanation for your edit in the edit summary. And yeah, comments that are **directly** relevant to the post are fine, but ideally they *will* result in edits that capture the most essential information.

Answer (score 4):

#### Context

You can "relate a comment to another comment" by the judicious use of minimal quoting or using a clear referent to provide context. For example, the previous sentence includes six quoted words; I think it's pretty obvious what this answer is referring to, even without broader context.

#### Linking

You have 600 characters for a comment. You can spend a few of them on a link, if you truly feel it's necessary. Links for each comment can be copied to your clipboard by right-clicking the timestamp next to the relevant comment, and pasting that into yours.

#### Comments Shouldn't Be Conversations

If there are so many comments that it's not clear who or what you're commenting about, then:

1. You need to write targeted comments that provide context.
2. You are abusing comments, and should probably ask a question, post an answer, or move it over to chat.
3. Someone should probably flag the thread for moderator attention.

The only notable exception is meta, where ridiculously long comment threads are generally tolerated. See [Revisiting the rep cap (yes, again)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136059) for an example of long (but tolerated) comment threads that would be off-topic or noise on Stack Overflow proper.