# Limiting rep per post

Tags: discussion, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

My apologies if I ask this wrongly.  There are so many related topics to this and I tried to read through the biggest ones.

The discussion that caught my attention the most and what I would like to further discuss was [Revisiting the rep cap (yes, again)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136059/revisiting-the-rep-cap-yes-again)  From that, Jon's biggest point is that a reputation cap per post would be much better than a general reputation cap.

### The Problem

A trend that I have been seeing is the highest reputation posts come from being the first to answer easy questions on new technology.  A good example of this is found in the Git and Android tags.  Take these questions for example:

[How do I push a new local branch to a remote Git repository and track it too?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765421/how-to-push-a-new-local-branch-to-remote-repo-and-track-it-too) (has only 9 other answers)

[How to modify existing, unpushed commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-do-i-edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git) (32 questions/16 answers for asker, 9 questions/39 answers for answerer)

[How to undo last commit(s) in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-the-last-git-commit)

[How do I delete a Git branch both locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely)

["Debug certificate expired" error in Eclipse Android plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194808/debug-certificate-expired-error-in-eclipse-android-plugins)

In fact, you can just search by tag and then sort by votes.  Looking at the links I posted, you can see people with over 50k rep from answering just one question.  To me, it does not seem like the intent of the reputation system is to greatly reward those who were fortunate enough to ask or answer a very popular question at the right time.

### Why It Matters

Believe it or not, but Stack Overflow rep is becoming increasingly important.  I put my Stack Overflow profile on LinkedIn and have had several recruiters contact me because they saw I have 3k rep.  The current system is greatly devaluing my profile and falsely glorifying profiles that have answered 9 questions.  I may be biased, but I think I am worth more to the Stack Overflow community with my 167 questions answered compared to 9 questions answered, yet my reputation does not reflect that (3k vs 54k).

From Jon's discussion, it seemed like people generally liked his suggestions but was hesitant to make a retroactive change that would affect 101,727 users.  The problem is more with the legacy posts that were made before the daily cap so changes would need to be made to both.

Comment: As someone that has worked hard to breach the top 50 in 18 months, I am fine with the rep cap system as it stands today. Any recruiter that only looks at your reputation score should be given a wide berth *anyway*. They should look at the average score per answer for a given tag, really, which *is not* capped.

Comment: "but StackOverflow rep is becoming increasingly important"  I disagree.  At the end of the day it's just not *that* important.

Comment: The accepted answer over at Jon's question cites statistics that indicate his system would actually have a negative effect on the low end. Personally I've accumulated a pretty large amount of rep pretty fast and have only hit the cap twice so I don't see why it's an issue. I agree that a time out makes sense though (for yours and Jon's arguments).

Comment: To have 50k rep from answering one question, bounties aside, you'd need 5000 upvotes if there was no cap, or 20 votes per day for 250 days. Only 3 posts on SO have 5000 upvotes, and 2 of the authors concerned have >100k rep from their other posts. So there is only one person “with over 50k rep from answering just one question”. One outlier isn't worth the time I spent checking your facts.

Comment: Some of these posts are pretty dated. Early adopters will always end up benefiting in some way, and this is one of them. Don't think negatively of them, be inspired by them so that in a few years, you too may have a post which generates 50,000 rep.

Comment: I'm in favour of a per post rep cap, but the perceived devaluation of SO rep wouldn't be affected by it one bit. It's not those few outliers who are driving it, it's the droves of users giving cheap answers to trivial questions in popular tags. SO rep as a measure of anything else than activity on SO is really useless long term, even though high rep still often coincides with actual competence

Comment: But +1 for research and bringing this up again

Comment: @Gilles obviously I selected the outlier to make my point. There are tons in the 10+ upvote range which is my main target.

Comment: @Radiodef I think you are confusing my point. The current cap is not so much the problem but rather an additional per post cap should also be implemented, or I guess it could replace it.

Comment: @Servy I consider something that can affect actual career decisions to be important.

Comment: I think if you target even relatively low upvote questions for the cap you're in significant danger of making Stack Exchange 'not fun anymore'; half of us keep coming back to chase the 'next big score'. From 'not fun anymore' its only a short hop to 'not existing anymore'

Comment: @trevor-e Ok, that git-reset answer has probably earned its author as much reputation as I have for all my answers. And while it's a useful one (it's even helped me), it may not be worth that much. So what? It's still an outlier. It's normal not to optimize a system for outliers. As Pekka notes, here are many many many more people who earn lots of reputation from lots of low-effort posts (copied code snippets, bare links, answering questions instead of closing them…). At least these outliers have posted something useful.

Comment: @Gilles I would value the people who answer 10 simple and repetitive questions higher than the person who got lucky getting 10+ upvotes for copy and pasting info from the documentation. It's not very clear what the community values more though. I look at rep linearly where I expect those with 10k+ rep to be experts rather than lottery winners.

Comment: FYI As this is your first meta post I should let you know the negative score is not an indication that you shouldn't have posted this or that it's poorly written (actually I think it's very well written) but that people disagree with the feature request

Comment: Thanks Richard, I do remember reading that somewhere. Hopefully I do not come across as being sensitive to down votes. I think the responses so far have been helpful.

Comment: I should point out that not once has someone contacted me to offer me a job or contract based on my reputation score, but I have received many such contacts based on individual answers that I'd written. Some of those answers had only one or two upvotes on them, but were of such value to someone working on a very specific problem that people wrote (and in one case, found and called my office phone number). Find some area that you are uniquely qualified to help people with and write clear, detailed answers, and that will benefit you more in the long run than any imaginary points.

Comment: @trevor-e If you're a great programmer you're going to have no problems find a job regardless of your SO rep.  If you're not a good programmer is highly unlikely that you'll end up landing a great job just because you have a high SO rep that you earned without actually having any expertise.  That you think a recruiter is going to look at the score, and nothing else, and end up hiring someone who is not a qualified programmer is rather absurd.

Comment: I'm not saying that employers will come out and offer a job purely due to reputation score.  I'm saying that it definitely helps getting noticed and keeping your resume on the stack and not in the trashcan.

Answer (score 12):

While in some cases, you may have a point, this isn't enough of a problem to justify a change.

- There aren't many of these incidents; they typically happen, as you say, with new technology, and even then most of the questions don't achieve this sort of status
- These questions are helping a *broad* range of people anyway - thus, the contributions have significant worth to the community
- New technology often needs the most help, as such technology is not often well-documented and programming practices are not well-established

If you can point to multiple good examples where:

1. The post received >100 upvotes.
2. The post did not actually help many people.
3. The problem is very, very specific.

Then you may have more of a point  - but even so, it doesn't make up enough of a percentage of posts to make a significant difference.

Additionally, remember that we're playing the game to help people, not to earn points - if you are here for another reason, you may be heartily disappointed :]

Comment: I'll also note that posts which satisfy your 3 points tend to get all their attention at once. So they already get nerfed by the daily repcap.

Comment: @Mysticial Ooh, that's a good point. I wonder how much rep these posts typically accrue... may have to query that at some point. (Also: profile picture++)

Comment: Not much. Here's a [query I wrote a long time ago](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/109508/how-much-rep-would-a-user-have-without-a-specific-post) to answer this question:. Most "interesting but useless" questions don't give much.

Comment: @Mysticial Interesting query. Thank you!

Comment: Just as one example, I'd actually argue that my [most popular answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6841479/22656) almost certainly hasn't *really* helped many people. I don't think that many people are affected by the time zone in China in the 1920s (a very, very specific situation). I think the upvotes there have been for "it's an interesting situation" rather than "this was helpful in a practical way". I agree that it's the exception rather than the rule though. (And it doesn't actually affect my rep, other than to hit the cap earlier in the day.)

Comment: Your bullets are good points.  Here's another example of what I'm getting at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535298/how-to-rotate-the-android-emulator-display

The post literally just says what buttons to press to rotate the emulator screen, and from it he received 700 votes.  That's 70% of the way to receiving a gold Android tag medal.  If I see someone posting and they have a tag medal then I know to trust their answers, and this inflation is detrimental to that (though in this case the user happens to be a good frequent poster).

Comment: @trevor Almost all heuristic systems like these have noise, I agree. The question is, how much of a difference does it make? And I think the answer is, not much.