# How would an answering days badge set work?

Tags: discussion, answers, badges

Recently, we rolled out a badge set for [asking questions habitually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges). Naturally, I wondered if we could do something similar for *answering*. If you take the same criteria and simply change `PostTypeId` to 2 (for answers), you get the following breakdown on Stack Overflow:

```
activity  gold silver bronze
--------  ---- ------ ------
Asking    1195  13646 133778
Answering 5935  26299 132931
```

Two things to keep in mind:

1. Closed questions don't factor into either criteria, since we are looking at answers.
2. Answers are sometimes deleted when a question is deleted, which is often outside the control of the person answering.

What the numbers tell me is that people are already well incentivized to come back every day to answer questions. Someone like [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc), who has posted well-recieved answers on 1625 of his 1886 days on the site, is hardly going to be motivated by another gold badge. Cranking up the requirements would make the gold badge more rare, but would it provide **extra motivation** for newer users to *become* regular answerers? [The reputation cap already does that job.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136060/1438)

So while I like the idea of a complementary set of badges for answering questions, I don't know what the benefit would be. Can we structure a badge set for answering questions that motivates people to habitually answer questions, but is not redundant to existing motivations?

Comment: Attempting to improve the quality of the site at large might affect the motivation more than anything else.

Comment: Another thing is to define what _well-received_ implies.  A question that probably ought to be closed in the first place is often upvoted by those answering it.  Then there are those who would upvote a question if their answer is accepted.  Moreover, there are "brothers" too -- who would upvote each others posts.  No doubt, all of these qualify as _well-received_.

Comment: I have been slacking on the job for 261 days?... (me hiding in shame). That being said, the actual issue would be the limit of the bronze/silver/gold badge model. A different (and complementary) system measuring the "degree of achievement" rather than just the "achievement" itself would be more interesting. Posting a well-received answer for 100 days is cute. Doing the same over 1000 days should be somehow noted too. (the "degree of achievement" is valid for other goals too: 1000 votes in Java isn't much. 1000 in golang actually is)

Comment: @VonC: More likely you've had answers deleted along with a question which negates the day. That would be one of the things I'd want to adjust if I pursue this badge further. One solution would be to award multiple golds (you'd get 16), but that doesn't seem sufficient either somehow. (Not that I have the foggiest idea how to not your level of dedication other than to simply put the stats on the profile somehow.)

Comment: @JonEricson I am not for getting a given gold badge multiple times (or I would get 18+ Fanatic ones). That is what I am talking about with my "degree of achievement": this isn't covered by the bronze/silver/gold badge model, and a new parallel "ranking" system (not just votes) would be an interesting addition in order to better characterize a user action on the site.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think it's necessary to give further incentives for answering. We already have enough what with reputation; nice/good/great answer, enlightened & guru badges. There's also the Epic and Legendary badges for hitting the rep cap on 50 and 150 days (something I've still to achieve even here on MSE).

All these provide enough inducement to answer. Adding more badges will only encourage people to answer the borderline and bad questions whereas what we should be doing is encouraging people to improve them or find duplicates (there are only so many ways to ask "why I am getting a NullReferenceException", for example).

Comment: Even if the parameters were tweaked, like demanding +2 score and without counting closed/duplicates?

Comment: @AndreSilva - probably. I really don't see the need. What the sites lack is *good* questions, not good answers. We already have those in abundance.