# Allow a user to uncheck his/her own answer

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow author of accepted answer to delete it in certain circumstances](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14932/allow-author-of-accepted-answer-to-delete-it-in-certain-circumstances)

It turns out I was mistaken. It happens from time to time. I answered a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427075/using-sharpsvn-how-can-you-export-a-file-memory-instead-of-to-the-filesystem/3427297#3427297), the answer was accepted, and I was later shown to be wrong.

I would like to un-accept the answer I gave and remove my post, but cannot. I think it would be beneficial to allow an answerer to uncheck their own answer if they deem another answer more correct than their own.

It is worth considering what to do with the reputation in this scenario as well. My thoughts are that the 15 points for the bad answer are forfeit, even in the face of honesty. I am ambivalent about what to do with the 2 points to the acceptor.

Comment: A related request for allowing you to delete your answer if it is erroneously accepted under certain circumstances: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14932/allow-author-of-accepted-answer-to-delete-it-in-certain-circumstances

Comment: @grace the title is about deleting, but reading the content, it's exactly the same thing.

Comment: I don't think this is an exact duplicate of the previous question -- they are different proposals to handle similar problems.  And I think it's a great feature suggestion.

Comment: I believe it to be an exact duplicate, and you can read my answer on the dupe.