# Is it okay to delete an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, useless-answers

So, someone asks a question and we all post answers to it. Later on down the line, if you think your answer isn't worthwhile to be there as compared to the other answers, is it okay to delete it?

This way, users can increase the ratio of his/her accepted to total answers.

Comment: Oded's answer is correct. But that aside: I would not worry about the ratio of total/accepted answers. (But of course, if other answers are better and yours does not add anything, then deleting is fine. I'd even appreciate that!)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to delete one of your answers, delete it. That's why there is a delete link.

Comment: Then why are there double-standards, why cant we delete asked question despite having the delete link.

Comment: @refhat - An answer represents your work only. A question that has answers (and that got upvoted) represents work by others - upvotes mean others found it valuable, so deleting it is not as easy. Can you link to an example of a question you can't delete?

Comment: if some guy upvoted an answer and then another one downvoted the same answer, all in all this question has 1 answer with 0 votes(neutralised). can this be deleted

Comment: @refhat - As far as I know, an answer can be deleted regardless how many upvotes it got.

Comment: Can't find the link, but I believe you can delete your answer unless it has been accepted with the green check by the OP.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14932/allow-author-of-accepted-answer-to-delete-it-in-certain-circumstances

Comment: @Oded: I am talking about this question. It has 0 reps but i cant delete it:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943734/how-to-locate-a-latitude-and-longitude-with-jvector-map-plugin

Comment: @refhat - That's a question. Not an _answer_. You asked about deleting _answers_. Is that what you meant to ask about?

Comment: The famous SO message, This question has answers and cant be deleted, flag it for moderator attention instead. This is what I mean to say by double standards. all in all it has 0 reps I think i should be able to delete this.

Comment: correct I asked about answer, but I am just wondering why cant we delete the questions if we can delete answers, as per your argument no 2, in the comment thread.

Comment: @refhat - Double standard? Someone took the time to _answer_ your question. And others have decided the question has merit (even got 1 upvote) - the community did not close and delete it. The rule is that you can't delete a question if it has answers, because that should be a _community_ decision, not yours (since all questions/answers are licensed as commons).

Comment: @refhat - But that question _did get an answer_.

Comment: true, i agree but there are cases where answers could go wrong(even by mistake) you referred a good example http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14932/allow-author-of-accepted-answer-to-delete-it-in-certain-circumstances

Comment: @refhat - That's about someone's _answer_, not question. If you are going to pick up an example, make it relevant.

Comment: I agree with you everywhere..

Answer (score 2):

It is, but not for this reason "*This way, users can increase the ratio of his/her accepted to total answers.*"

Don't do that, I have even seen how after some time some answers got a lot more upvotes than the accepted one. **Just because it was not the best answer to the OP eyes, doesn't mean it is not the best answer or that it can help future visitors**.