# Why do people with high reputation get upvoted even for worthless answers?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, high-rep-users

Please forgive me if I am making some very big mistake by asking a silly question like this. By no means do I want to disrespect any of the intellectual people here on Stack Overflow.

I read a few question and answers on Stack Overflow and found that people with very high reputation get upvotes very easily even if the answers are not worthy to get so many of the upvotes.

An example of such a post is this question:- [Can we execute a .bat file in post build event command line in visual studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491394/can-we-execute-a-bat-file-in-post-build-event-command-line-in-visual-studio/1491412#1491412)

I know that the obvious answer could be "yes" but that's just an example.

In this I found that people have  given upvotes and also the answer was accepted, just because it's Jon Skeet, the most reputed and most intelligent guy of the world, who has answered.

If some other guy who had less reputation had answered this in a similar manner, then we can very easily see that people would have downvoted and voted to delete the answer. Or the community or other moderators would have deleted the answer.

Why is this sort of behavior present?

P.S. Jon Skeet: Sir please don't get me wrong. I respect you the most on this planet and by no means do I doubt your intelligence. I took you just because all of us respect and appreciate you, and maybe many can understand what I am trying to convey easily. And if by any means I am disrespecting you then please forgive me. But trust me that's not intentional or personal.

**EDIT:-**

To mark another example as pointed by someone in comments:-

[Issues with ANDs and ORs (COBOL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342218/issues-with-ands-and-ors-cobol/4342263#4342263)

So how come this answer deserves 117 reps ;) Just becasue the person who is answering it has high reputation.

Trust me there are many more which you people can find as your reputations are higher and I have few restrictions because of less rep. But that's how I have seen it.

Comment: You know that you are refering to a single question of the very begining of SO? Do you have more than this exception from acient history?

Comment: Sir please forgive me but I am very nervous right now after asking this question. But just wanted to know!

Comment: @user2638798 but is it happening now or was it happening in an era well gone?

Comment: I know the feeling, but I think that [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101988/213634) answer sums it up pretty well.

Comment: The point is why someone from the Community or the Moderator have not deleted it! Dont you people agree that if anyone else would have done the same then either the Community or the Moderators would have deleted it!

Comment: normally, we do not delete accepted answers? or d owe

Comment: And please dont mark it as duplicate as this question has nothing to do with that one. I agree that people with high repuation write there answers very well and they should be awarded the rewards. But I m making a point at Community or Moderators working. May be I have made a very wrong point and many would send me to HELL today!

Comment: **ALSO TO MARK IT AGAIN TO ALL JON SKEET LOVERS. I AM HIS FAN TOO AND BY NO MEANS I WANT TO DISRESPECT HIM.** So please mercy me

Comment: I have seen this kind of thing too. I guess when a high rep user answers and we find the answer unclear or lacking, we're more likely to assume that it's because we missed something ourselves. And thus, less likely to downvote or flag.

Comment: @AndersUP:- I just wanted to know that is it that Community or moderators dont delete those answers which are answered by people with high reputation or is there any other reason. Because I have many times that Community deletes those answers which have been accpted also but are of low quality. P.S. I am feeling nervous as I took JON SKEET and he is the best and all his lovers will hate me for this! But trust me that my intetionas are not bad.

Comment: *"please dont mark it as duplicate as this question has nothing to do with that one"* -- too bad you didn't explain why you think it's different. To me, it seems to be a duplicate.

Comment: The question is four years old. Can you come up with a better, more recent example?

Comment: I also think you should get more examples to make a point. Also, it looks like you just took Jon Skeet as an example so you can praise him like a god and sacrifice your firstborn as apology afterwards in the comments... If I was him I'd be scared.

Comment: Here's an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342218/issues-with-ands-and-ors-cobol/4342263#4342263. This makes Joel Spolsky the All Time #2 COBOL answerer, with 127 answers fewer than the #1, but more than 1/4 of votes of #1. The other answer is better, and has an amazing (for COBOL code) score of 18, a side-effect I'd say. However, it is the way it is.

Comment: A firstborn can come in very handy, e.g. for light work around the house or as a patsy in a hit-and-run. But these days, the costs for upkeep would probably be prohibitive.

Comment: @BillWoodger:- Thanks a lot for helping me although the question is closed and I didnt got my answer which I was expecting neither I have privileges to reopen my question. !

Comment: If you can find more examples, I'm sure the question can be reopened. As it is now it looks like you're basing your hypothesis on a single answer (out of literally millions). And no-one has magical powers to find similar cases; everyone has access to the same search tools regardless of their rep.

Comment: Re your new example; Its worth noting that 20K isn't actually that high in the grand scheme of things; however, if you're around long enough you'll have some abnormalities. If you have enough questions (as a high rep user will) you will have some that just end up being highly upvoted (that said there certainly is a cult of jon skeet that gives him bonus attention and votes=attention*quality; not that that makes any difference, i'm sure he'd hit the rep cap either way)

Answer (score 12):

First off, that's a terrible question.  Both the title and the body simply read:

> Can we execute a .bat file in post build event command line in visual studio?

I'd argue that the question didn't deserve much more of an answer.  It did get several good answers though, and two of them are upvoted much more highly than Jon's.  I'd say that and the 5 downvotes on Jon's answer quash any arguments of favoritism.

---

I want to address the following comments you made above.

> I just wanted to know that is it that Community or moderators dont delete those answers which are answered by people with high reputation or is there any other reason.

The community and moderators *do* delete answers from people with high reputation.  Jon (for one example) has an entire page of deleted answers, but he mostly seems to have the good sense to delete them himself when they aren't of the best quality.  I myself (for one other example) have *hundreds* of deleted answers, *many* of which were deleted by other moderators.

> Because I have many times that Community deletes those answers which have been accpted also but are of low quality.

<strike>I'm pretty sure the community *can't* delete accepted answers</strike> It's very difficult for the community to delete accepted answers unless they are negatively voted, which is why I rarely do so myself.  Also note that [author's can't delete their own accepted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14932/allow-author-of-accepted-answer-to-delete-it-in-certain-circumstances), which might be another reason they tend to stick around even if they're not the best quality.

Comment: Sir my concern is not about Jon. Please dont concentrate on him. I took him just to make my point. I have found this many times. My point is not to test anyone. Just wanted to know if this is right!

Comment: @ususer2638798 You've concentrated on one person by providing only one example. If you have a larger point to make, please give more examples.

Comment: Sir I have not concentrated on any person. Its just a question. I have seen many times that Community or moderators delete these sort of answers even if they are accpted and upvoted. Although if you think that i am making an unnecessary point then do forgive me. But I thought of it! And  I dont know inspite of me telling so many times that my concern is not to a person specific why you all are pointing to a specific person. Please understand my point. May be I am not very clear! Sorry for that :(

Comment: @user2638798 See my edits.

Comment: **I'm pretty sure the community can't delete accepted answers, which is why I rarely do so myself.** No Sir I have a seriosu doubt on this but I have seen community deleting the question and answer both which were accepted. My reputation is not that much to see the deleted answer else I would have tried to search that. !

Comment: @user2638798 Questions aren't accepted, only answers.  The community can vote to delete a question that *has* an accepted answer, but I don't think they can vote to delete just the accepted answer.

Comment: My point was that Community has deleted the question as well as answers. Although the answers were accpted. May be I missed the working of Community. Presently reading about Community only. :)

Comment: @BilltheLizard _I don't think they can vote to delete just the accepted answer_ Let me try to find an example that I came across in the review queue last week it was an accepted answer and it allowed me to vote to delete it.

Comment: @bluefeet I can flag accepted answers for deletion on Sci-Fi and Fantasy, is that the same thing?  (I only have one 10k account where I'm not a moderator, so I don't have a lot of experience with 10k tools.)

Comment: @BilltheLizard Yes it is the same thing.  When you are in the 10k tools, if there is something with a negative vote count, you are given the option to cast a vote to delete.  I believe that even if it is an accepted answer, if it receives enough votes to delete it will be.

Comment: @bluefeet Ah, ok.  Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Actually, I looked again I am wrong. The vote to delete answers comes with the 20k trusted user.

Comment: @bluefeet Oh! That explains why I don't see it anywhere.  I don't qualify on any site but SO and Meta.

Answer (score 9):

That answer wasn't the best Jon has ever done - we all have answers that we're not particularly proud of.

Jon didn't have a huge reputation score back then. It might have been huge comparatively speaking at the time, but nothing like it is today. So you shouldn't correlate the voting on an ancient answer with his current rep total. Those votes look more like *"we agree with you"* rather than *"that was a great answer"*. (Note that it **is an answer**, so don't flag it for converting to a comment). Regardless of whether it is the marked answer, if you believe it to be low in quality you have two options:

- down vote it
- edit it and make it better

(it's not often you will EVER get a legitimate chance to edit one of Jon's posts).

You should also note that StackOverflow has become considerably less forgiving of answers like that - these days it would get voted down, someone would leave a comment, people would have a go at flagging it.

Comment: Sir as I am continuosuly making a point that please dont concentrate on Jon. The point is why someone from the Community or the Moderator have not deleted it! Sorry if I am being too stupid!

Comment: "it's not often you will EVER get a legitimate chance to edit one of Jon's posts."  I can see that poor answer get edited into community wiki status REAL fast now! :-)

Comment: I disagree that it shouldn't be flagged. It is just noise that anyone encountering the question has to read first before getting to useful content. As it is accepted Jon won't be able to delete it himself so it needs deletion by moderator or community.

Comment: @user2638798 Moderators are not quality filters or ajudicators, they respond to flagged issues. This is an answer, just a low quality one, so the appropriate thing to do is down vote or fix it. If it gets to negative votes then trusted users (>20K rep) can vote to delete it (although they might not be able to if it is the marked answer).

Comment: @slugster - But without calling out specific posts on meta (as here) in order to get the required downvotes the community cannot delete it. A discrete flag seems much better to me.

Comment: @MartinSmith I agree - personally I think it would be the right thing to do if a mod took the initiative and converted it to a comment. But doing that means bending a few rules and/or definitions and/or moderator protocols. Let's just see if it goes negative, it's currently at +1 and the question has been closed.

Answer (score 2):

This specific example, you are running into 2 issues, neither of which is tied to who answered the question.

1. In SO time, the post is ancient history.  Things were much different in 2009 than they are now.  Such an answer now would have been better as a comment and likely would have been flagged as NAN if it was posted today.  Heck, maybe even Jon wanted to delete the answer since it is just a comment but since it is accepted, he can't.
2. The answer correctly answers the question.  So when such an answer correctly addresses the question, the problem is the question, not the answer.

Both of those combined explain the upvotes.  And frankly, I think more than a few of the downvotes could be due to who answered the question too because they could be saying "Jon, how could you post such a poor answer".

Now in general, you should treat any answer like this just as you would any other poor quality answer... though downvotes and comments.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this too - answers by high rep users get upvotes, when I think the same answer by a low rep user would have been ignored or downvoted.

I guess when we see an answer by a high-rep user, and we find it unclear or lacking, we are more likely to assume that it's because we don't understand it. And therefore less likely to downvote, flag or comment.

It could also be that a high reputation score and lots of badges contribute to a [halo effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_effect), making us inclined to respond positively to posts by that user. We should be judging posts by the value of the post **only**, of course, but we're only human.

The sad consequence is that low-rep users may be held to a higher standard than high-rep users, even if we should all be held to the same standard.

The best thing to do is to be as objective as you can on Stack Overflow. If you think an answer is wrongly upvoted, don't get worked up about it - downvote and/or comment. If that doesn't help, move on. There are more important things in life than internet points.