# My accepted answer accumulating downvotes - what is expected action, if any?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, accepted-answer

My accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1685286/18157 (from Nov 2009) has gone from +8 to -2 (i.e. 10 downvotes) even though AFAICT it actually answers the question as it was asked.  The top upvoted answer doesn't seem to relate directly to the question but another issue that results in similar errors.

Since it seems a lot of people feel it doesn't address the question, should I take some action, such as deleting the answer?  I've never encountered this before... what is the proper behavior in this case?

EDIT: With the help of a few others the answer has been deleted. Thanks.

Comment: This is a problem with accepted answers, if people disagree they'll very agressively downvote in the hope the answer is deleted,  not realising it can't be deleted

Comment: The problem with your answer is that it explains the problem in a single sentance but does not provide any solution. It should rather be a comment IMO. People trying to bring better answers to the top by downvoting yours.

Comment: I agree that there are a couple of other answers that actually answer the question and provide a solution, so I would delete my answer if I could.

Comment: I could vote to delete it if you would like...?

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow I don't think you can delete an accepted answer either, can you?

Comment: @psubsee2003 I can *vote* to delete it. (3 votes from 20k+ user deletes any answer) In fact, there's already one delete vote on it (not me)

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow true, but I don't think the last delete vote would be allowed until it is unaccepted.

Comment: I tried to vote-to-delete but it won't let me (and I have 35.9K rep). I'm going to flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: @ExUmbris That's because you're the owner of it. I just deletevoted as well

Comment: Last delete vote cast. :-)

Comment: It's gone, thanks for the help.  Not sure how to resolve _this_ question now... :-)

Comment: Perhaps it's time to revisit this old feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14932/allow-author-of-accepted-answer-to-delete-it-in-certain-circumstances