# What to do with my popular but mediocre answer

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting

My answer gets upvotes.    Someone else's later answer shows mine is speculative at best, wrong at worst.  Mine keeps getting upvotes and never even one downvote despite the newer answer's better information.

I suppose this is an example of the [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem), although I don't deserve that title.  More of a hastily drawn and poorly aimed gun.   That question addresses the meta problem about best approaches to scoring.

My question here is .... what should I do?    What I did do is upvote the better answer and edit mine to improve it.   Is that it?

Comment: Deleting is an option.  My edited answer however is not speculative and contains information not in other answers.  It may not deserve the upvotes but it may be useful to OP and others.

Comment: "Someone else's later answer shows mine is speculative at best, wrong at worst." If you agree with this you could edit it into the answer. Just be honest and let voters do the rest. A mediocre answer is still an answer and voters might see more in it than you think.

Answer (score 10):

> My question here is .... what should I do? What I did do is upvote the better answer and edit mine to improve it. Is that it?

If you can improve yours to get to the same level as the better answer, then yeah, that's mostly it.

If even after editing, some of the problems still remain, you might want to consider deleting your answer in favor of the better one. A small comment underneath your answer explaining why you deleted it should be enough to prevent someone else undeleting it.

Comment: However, [if your answer has been accepted, you won’t be able to delete it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14932/allow-author-of-accepted-answer-to-delete-it-in-certain-circumstances?r=SearchResults) without a mod’s help.